# Save and Update data from custom html forms in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've created a custom HTML form for my model, just like I want to add a post from the front-end. I already created a page with the name **add-post.html**

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="title" type="text">
        <textarea spellcheck="false" name="description"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="image" @change="fileName" multiple />
        <select required name="priority">
           <option value="Low" selected>Low</option>
           <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
           <option value="High">High</option>
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox" name="on_hold">
        <button type="submit">Add ToDo</button>
    </form>
```

Here's my **model.py**

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='todo/images/')
    description = RichTextField()
    Low, Medium, High = 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'
    priorities = [
        (Low, 'Low'),
        (Medium, 'Medium'),
        (High, 'High'),
    ]
    priority = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=priorities,
        default=Low,
    )
    on_hold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

No, I want to use the above custom HTML form to post data and save it to this model database. instead of using `{% form.as_p %}`

And I also created a particular page to update this post from the front-end but don't know how to make it work.

Can you please guide me on how can I save data from the custom form and also update it from the custom form?
Appreciate your response :)

Answer (score 0):

@Mubasher Rehman - You are almost there

forms.py

```
class TodoCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('title','image','description','priorities','priority','on_hold',)
```

views.py

```
  from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
    from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CreatProduct(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    model = Todo
    form_class = TodoCreationForm
    template_name = "add_post.html"
    success_message = "Todo was created successfully"
    error_message = "Error saving the Todo, check fields below."
```

add_post.html

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I have already created forms.py and using it. But the only problem here is that I want to use that custom form instead of using {{ form.as_p }}

Answer (score 0):

@Mubasher Rehman - I fought this problem myself for awhile and finally found a solution. My situation was much different than yours, but try this:

In your **views.py** overwrite the **form_valid** method like so:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            t= Todo.objects.create(title='title', image='image', description='description', priority='priority', on_hold='on_hold')
            t.save()

    return super(ModelView, self).form_valid(form)
```